# How to upload,get and update an image or file in laravel ? What is the correct way?

Tags: php, laravel, image, laravel-passport, laravel-storage

What is the correct way to upload,update and get an image or file in laravel ? I had gone through laravel docs and other references but its confusing.Can anyone show a complete simple example for

- any disk configuration in filesystems.php
- a simple method to upload and update image in controller
- and what will be the image full url?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

input type file name is **image** you can store directly into **images** folder

```
return $path = $request->image->store('images');
```

Comment: what to do if i need to store image which should not be publicly accessible ? Only authenticated users should be able to view it. and how to view the image?

Comment: you need to use authentication for image accessibility for authenticated users only https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/image-accessibility-for-authenticated-users-only